# Connection timed out no servers could be reached, port is open but connection refused

Tags: centos, dns, dnsmasq

I'm trying to set up a dnsmasq on a CentOS 7. The machine is on local IP 192.168.0.50. From the DNS server I get the answer when using `nslookup`. But, when I use nslookup from another machine in same local network I get a

> ```
> connection timed out; no servers could be reached
> ```

**/etc/dnsmasq.conf** configuration:

```
conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d,.rpmnew,.rpmsave,.rpmorig
resolv-file=/etc/resolv.conf.upstream
```

**/etc/dnsmasq.d/ma_config_dns.conf** configuration:

```
strict-order
listen-address=192.168.0.50
listen-address=127.0.0.1
cache-size=5000
```

**/etc/resolv.conf** configuration:

```
search novalocal
nameserver 192.168.0.50
```

**netstat -tulpn :**

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12224/dnsmasq
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      12224/dnsmasq
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           12224/dnsmasq
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                12224/dnsmasq
```

**/etc/hosts :**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.0.172 vm1.novalocal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out there is an external firewall in the remote infrastructure that was blocking the port.

Answer (score 0):

Did you opened your firewall? It can done with these commands.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=53/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=53/udp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: the firewall on my local machine was open

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with iptables and selinux; you must check all network services status once on your machine.

The issue I found is network.service ; was failing on the vm.